# Saving a string in sharedpreferences in Login class to be used in MainActivity - Cannot refer to the non-final local variable editor defined

Tags: java, android, session, android-intent

I've built a login and I'm wanting my app to store the username used at login as the session name so I can pull information from the database depending on who is logged in.

The login works fine, however I'm using sharedpreferences for the first time to save the variable in **Login.java** then I am going to call it in **MainActivity.java** to run through an SQL statement.

Here is my **Login.java** - I tried using intents at first to send the boolean **session** and **username** through, but I can't quite get the logic working in MainActivity that is already there **(the onResume() method)** so I have decided to used sharedpreferences but I get the error `Cannot refer to the non-final local variable editor defined in an enclosing scope` underlining `editor.` in the if statement.

Basically:

1) Should I use the intents I have already tried to implement to store a session name and boolean, or do I use sharedpreferences? If so

2) If the answer is sharedpreferences, how come it won't let me use `editor.putString` and `editor.apply();` inside an onClick?

Help please! hurting my head a bit haha.

```
public class Login extends Activity   {
    DB db = new DB(this);
    boolean session = false;    
    int visited = 1;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login); 

        final EditText usernameET=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameET);
        final EditText passwordET=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordET);      
        final Button loginBTN=(Button)findViewById(R.id.loginBTN);
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        loginBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String username = usernameET.getText().toString();
                String password = passwordET.getText().toString();  
                boolean success = db.Login(username, password);       

                if(success)
                {
                    Log.d("login", "user logged");                  
                    session = true;                     
                    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("loginSuccess", session);
                    i.putExtra("sessionName", username);                  
                    editor.putString("Name", username);
                    editor.apply();
                    startActivity(i);                   

                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d("login", "user not logged");
                }
            }

        });





    }

}
```

Here is my **MainActivity.java**

**onResume() Method**

**An error in this method underlines `getBooleanExtra` saying `The method getBooleanExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String)`**

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.hasExtra("loginSuccess")) {
        boolean loginSuccess = intent.getBooleanExtra("loginSuccess");
        //Code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is where I was getting confused, I didn't see why it would need a default value if I was passing the value of the boolean through? Surely a default wouldn't matter. Anyway I'm testing now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 1:** The method `getBooleanExtra(String, boolean)` in the type `Intent` is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Method signature of `getBooleanExtra` asks for two parameters, but you are passing only one. First one is the key and second one is the default value if this key is not found.

Change

```
boolean loginSuccess = intent.getBooleanExtra("loginSuccess");
```

with

```
boolean loginSuccess = intent.getBooleanExtra("loginSuccess", false); // or true whichever you want as your default value
```

**Issue 2**: Cannot refer to the non-final local variable editor defined in an enclosing scope

just put the `final` identifier before `username`

```
final String username = usernameET.getText().toString();
```

> Should I use the intents I have already tried to implement to store a session name and boolean, or do I use sharedpreferences?

I would use `SharedPreference` because it won't force me to send data via Intent to every activity which needs the session information. I shall be able to get it anywhere without making any additional effort (sending data every time to every activity)

Comment: Thankyou! This is where I was getting confused, I didn't see why it would need a default value if I was passing the value of the boolean through? Surely a default wouldn't matter. I am testing it now - will get back to you asap

Comment: It needs default just to be safe.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thankyou Rohit5k2. I am going to keep the intents for now and when my app is more developed I will change to sharedpreferences.

Comment: i will select your answer in a minute :)